# How to communicate between TCP server in the background and methods in the main thread in C#?

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, tcp, server

I am working on a program with an UI on the main thread and a TCP server running in the background. Users communicate with the program via UI where a credit card machine processes the request from the users and send the results back in JSON format.As soon as a request received by the TCP server, it needs to process it by calling methods from the main thread, going to the credit card machine and the outcomes, in JSON format, need to be sent to the caller on the TCP server.
I am having difficulties in communication between background request and methods in the main thread to supply the response.
I Enquque each request and then call a method, FireTransaction(), that communicates with the credit card terminal to Dequque and process each request. FireTransaction() assigns a JSON object to the outJ variable and it is supposed to be the response. But the requests falls into a loop and while the credit card is processing it. How can I fix this?

```
 private void CallServer()
    {
        try
        {                
            int port = 7001;
            IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(serverAddress, port);

            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                string request = sr.ReadLine(); 
                string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
                string reqProcess = tokens[1];

                if (!cq.Contains(reqProcess))
                {
                    cq.Enqueue(reqProcess);
                    **Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { FireTransaction(); }));**

                    Thread.Sleep(17000);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outJ))
                        { System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outJ);
                            sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n");
                            sw.Write(outJ);
                        }                      
                }                                          
                client.Close();
            }               
        }

private async void FireTransaction()
    {
        double valAmount;
        string result;
        if (cq.TryDequeue(out result))
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                string[] command = result.Split(new[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                outJ = string.Empty;
                valAmount = Convert.ToDouble(command[1].ToString());
                outJ = await CreditCards.DoCredit(valAmount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the server works with HTTP requests, as illustrated by the HTTP 200 response in your example and returns JSON, it is a REST api, so why are you not using HttpClient to handle the comms? Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client .

Answer (score 0):

You should do the loop-stuff of processing the incoming request in a separate thread (each incoming connection should be processed in a separate thread).

For the `FireTransaction` you could pass in a `WaitHandle` like `ManualResetEvent` (or just an object if you want) that has been created in the processing thread.
After calling `FireTransaction` with the handle as an argument you wait for the handle to be signaled - and inside the FireTransaction you 'post' the signal after all processing has been done. That way you can get rid of the `Thread.Sleep` stuff...

And your `FireTransaction` method should return the processing result instead of setting a class (or global) variable.